# Is there a Java/JVM server that supports streaming binary over websocket?

Tags: java, binary, websocket

Does there exist an open source Java server/library/framework that supports bidirectional streaming of binary over websockets? I looked at a couple of them but couldn't find them mentioning binary support.

This explains what I want to do, I think: `http://binaryjs.com/` but I want a Java/JVM server instead of node.js.

So, I want to send raw bytes back and forth between client and server with as little overhead as possible.

If there is one, a direct link to the documentation about using binary would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat 7 has built in support for web sockets via [org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/index.html?org/apache/catalina/websocket/WebSocketServlet.html).

There is an example of writing binary data using a subclass of that class here:
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/webapps/examples/WEB-INF/classes/websocket/echo/EchoStream.java?view=markup

High level root of the how-to is here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I think I found the answer:
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Understanding-WebSocketHandler

There may be other servers that also handle it. I just needed to find at least one and it appears this does it.